# I'm using selenium (python module(3.8)) to open DocDroid.net website and send a PDF file from my desktop. But I am getting the following error

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
#Function to send pdf files to DocDroid website

def sendpdf():
    import selenium
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver=webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://www.docdroid.net/')
    upload_box=driver.find_element_by_id('select')
    upload_box.send_keys('C:\Users\User\Desktop\MySql.pdf')

sendpdf()
```

Basically I'm trying to use the selenium library in python to send a pdf file to DocDroid.net
The error I get :( :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install the win32com module using

```
pip install pywin32
```

Then use this code to upload your file.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import win32com.client
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.docdroid.net/")
driver.find_element_by_id("select").click()
time.sleep(4)
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.Sendkeys("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\aa.txt")  
shell.Sendkeys("~")
```

**Note:** Keep in mind that you are automation a website that has Google Captcha enabled.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'

Comment: If **pip install pywin32** is not working then you should try **pip install pypiwin32**

Comment: Ok that worked, but I can't click away from google captcha with the line:

Comment: driver.find_element_by_class("with-navbar").click()

Comment: why is it that way?

Comment: You can ask another question for captcha automation.